# Getting list of billing accounts in Azure using C# and new Azure.ResourceManager.Billing Namespace

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-automation

I am trying to use the new Azure Resource SDK in C# and I am just not coming right. The old deprecated namespace Microsoft.Azure.Management.Billing namespace was simple to achieve this ie:

```
var clientCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var billingClient = new BillingManagementClient(clientCredential);
var billingAccounts = await billingClient.BillingAccounts.ListAsync();
```

However, I need to migrate this to the newer Azure.ResourceManager.Billing namespace.

I have no problem connecting using the new SDK ie:

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://management.core.windows.net/.default" };

            var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            };

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantIdOrName, clientId, clientSecret, options);
       
client = new ArmClient(clientSecretCredential);
```

and then getting the subscription object ie
`SubscriptionResource subscription = await client.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();`

but this is where I get lost. All the methods I could find for billing in the SDK documentation seem to have the requirement of knowing the billing account you want to export/report on. I just can't work out the gap between having a client / subscription object instance and getting the list of billing accounts or how to link in the "Resources" needed to perform the request.
I have imported the following namespaces:

```
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Billing;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Billing.Models;
```

and looked at the following MS references:
[resourcemanager.billing-readme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/resourcemanager.billing-readme?view=azure-dotnet)
[azuresdk-net-mgmt-sample](https://aka.ms/azuresdk-net-mgmt-samples)
[GetUsageDetails](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-CXP-Developer-Support/blob/main/AzureConsumption/dotnet/GetUsageDetails/Readme.md)
and many others. (The last to try solve it looking at another namespace area. Is this the direction I should be going ie calling the HTTPS endpoint as there are no methods currently to do what I need in the SDK?)
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, even if is a good reference to any SDK documentation that has better guidelines than the current Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using below code to get the Usage Details of billing and it worked successfully like below:-

**Code:-**

```cs
//Sample Code

using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Consumption;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Consumption.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace AzureCostReport
{
    class Program
    {
        // Update the below constants with your Azure subscription ID, tenant ID, client ID, and client secret.

        private const string subscriptionId = "xxxxx2a7";
        private const string tenantId = "xxxxxxxxf9038592395";
        private const string clientId = "xxxxx31435cb";
        private const string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxA1zlgc~A";


        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Authenticate using a service principal.
            var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            // Get the bearer token
            var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" }));

            // Get the Cost details
            GetCostDetails(token).Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        private static async Task GetCostDetails(AccessToken token)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Token);

            //Invoke te Consumption details REST API
            var result = await client.GetAsync("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxx7/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?startDate=2023-10-01&endDate=2023-10-23&$top=1000&api-version=2017-06-30-preview");

            Console.WriteLine(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Code2 to retrieve billing accounts:-**

```cs
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Replace these with your Azure AD application registration details and subscription ID.
        string subscriptionId = "xxxxx2a7";
        string tenantId = "xxxxx395";
        string clientId = "xxxxx35cb";
        string clientSecret = "xxxxxxA1zlgc~A";

        string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
        string resource = "https://management.azure.com/";
        string apiUrl = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts?api-version=2019-10-01-preview";

        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential);

        if (authenticationResult == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed.");
            return;
        }

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {authenticationResult.AccessToken}");

        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(content);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve billing accounts. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.
Only issue is I kept getting 404 errors.
I believe the URL for billing is actually
`https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts?api-version=2019-10-01-preview`
So no subscriber details. This brings back a 200 response, but no values, so will have to see why that is unless the URL is still not correct.

Comment: Okay, its working now. Needed to grant Reader permissions to the service principal under the Cost Management section in Azure.